# Can a monster with many tentacles grapple multiple times or targets per round?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, grapple

Are there rules for the attacker to grapple multiple defenders? Can that attacker, with more than two arms, attack a new defender each round, or grapple many defenders as a full round action? I am looking for a RAW answer; if I have to I'll house rule it.

The creature I am making resembles a displacer beast, with six tentacles and a mouth like a lamprey. I would like to use the bite feature only if the defender is grappled; defenders breaking grapple will free themselves from the bite. While it can only bite one at a time, should a defender break free it can then bite another.

Comment: [Related answer that briefly touches on whether creatures without hands can Grapple with the Attack action](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/118716/41726)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Yes, some monsters can do this.

Check out the [Kraken](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/kraken).

It can Multiattack for three tentacle attacks in one action, each of which can grapple a different target, until all of its ten arms are full.

An ability like this would have to appear on a monster's stat block; it's not really generalizable.

Since you’re creatung the monster, you can give it a Multiattack action that says how its multiple grapples work.

Comment: A Roper (MM., p 261) would be a good lower level example of this, as well.